# How to set a cluster creator in CloudFormation to re-use it in lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have a CloudFormation stack that creates an EKS cluster and then runs a `kubectl` command in a lambda.

The problem is that the cluster is created with the access only for the user who ran the cloudformation stack (e.g. a human user). And in this case, the role that runs a lambda with `kubectl` fails with `You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)` because it's not the role that triggered the cloudfromation cluster creation stack.

I checked alternative solutions like `eksctl` where I can specify the role that will run the CloudFormation stack that creates a cluster, but creating a cluster with `eksctl` takes longer than 15 minutes and I can't use it inside lambda.

Is there a way to create an EKS cluster and have access to it from a lambda in the same cloudformation stack?

Answer (score 0):

you should create a custom IAM Service role for Cloudformaction STACK and LAMBDA.
You must guarantee this role has the required permissions on EKS service and

in the Permissions section you can find how a stack can assume a role.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html

And here is how to create a role for a service,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html

By default EKS set as administrator the role assumed when it is created.